# Railstutorial (Michael Hartl): Exercise 4.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax, methods, split

I don't get the answer to the following exercise from Hartl's Rails tutorial:

> By replacing the question marks in Listing 4.10 with the appropriate
>   methods, combine split, shuffle, and join to write a function that
>   shuffles the letters in a given string.

Listing 4.10:

```
>> def string_shuffle(s)
>>   s.split('').?.?
>> end
=> nil
>> string_shuffle("foobar")
```

Can someone please help me?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: With this approach you can't exactly shuffle a given string. You are in fact returning a NEW string, with the original string's letters shuffled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think just adding shuffle and join like you said should work:

```
def string_shuffle(s)
  s.split('').shuffle.join('')
end
```

The methods work from left to right. The split('') splits the word (s) into an array of separate letters. Shuffle then randomizes them. And join('') reverses the split, and puts it back into one word.

edit for clarification: The ('') is two single quotes, not one double quote. It should also work if you did split("") and join(""), since you're just trying to split and join on each character.

Comment: okay. and working with real values? where to put "puts s" or something similar? where declare the value?

Comment: Methods in ruby will return the last line, so the string will be returned. You can just say "puts string_shuffle(s)" and you'll print the shuffled string. As rewritten said in a comment, however, you are actually returning a new string with the original string's letters shuffled. For most cases, this is will basically do what you want it. The only case is if you define a variable and shuffle it, then the variable will still keep its original value. In which case, you'd want to do something like: 
s = "word"
s = string_shuffle(s)

Comment: @christophe Once you have `string_shuffle` method defined as above, you can call it as `string_shuffle("foobar")`. It gives different output each time you call it. Good luck with the RailsTutorial book. Do look up http://rubykoans.com/ (recommended at the end of the same section) later on to ramp up on your ruby skills.

Comment: Thank you for your exemplification!